# How to splice/remove an item from a list that was reversed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

so im displaying an array in reverse order

```
*ngFor="let item of items.reverse(); let i = index"
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to delete an item like so,

```
deleteItem(row) {
    this.items.splice(row,1);
  }
```

EXAMPLE...
array_items= [item1,item2,item3,item4]; So when its displayed, it will display array_items[3] first but if I try to delete it, it will delete array_items[0] . Does that make sense?
it doesn't delete the correct one. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you show us the array, and explain what you mean "doesn't delete the correct one".

Comment: array_items= [item1,item2,item3,item4];
So when its displayed, it will display array_items[3] first but if I try to delete it, it will delete array_items[0] . Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @kevner , It's better to use pipes to change value just in view . This is the use case of angular Pipe

Answer (score 1):

Since the list is reversed, the index will not be `row` but `this.items.length - row`, so I would try:

```
deleteItem(row) {
    this.items.splice(this.items.length - (row + 1), 1);
}
```

Comment: this got me going on the right track! thank you.. just needed to add that extra +1 
deleteItem(row) {
    this.items.splice(this.items.length - (row+1), 1);
}

Comment: @Kevner oops I missed that, updated the answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you reverse items in ngfor , the value doesn't change just in view and the items value in your component class reversed . I think you should use costume reverse pipe :

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({ name: 'reverse' })

    export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value) {
            return value.slice().reverse();
        }
    }
```

so the items reversed just in view.

```
*ngFor="let item of items | reverse let i = item.length + index - 1;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep start as the length of the array subtracting the currentIndex plus 1.

```
deleteItem(row){
  this.item.splice(this.item.length - (row +1), 1);
}
```

This will remove the original item from the array.

Comment: Hi @Adarsh yep this works... thanks for the help, mate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggess :

```
deleteItem(row){
this.item.splice(this.item.length - (row +1), 1);
}
```